# Confused riddle and poem?

Tags: riddle

These two stanzas are describing the same thing, ***what is it***?

> ```
> Glowing   brightly  as         though     a          sky
> Freely    oxidizing will       make       me         hot
> Find      me        obsequious as         your       son 
> Sparkling daily     as         gorgeous   as         sea
> Slowly    but       surely     developing life       tendrils 
> Aviary    friend    and        church     associated eminence
> ```

> ```
>  This  big - ger  of     twins  is     my   star-ter  
>  These two   dou -bles   are    the    same but  not  
>  The   se  - cond first, same   in     all  but  size  
>  The   odd   one, not    like   an  -  y    o -  ther  
>  This  last, the  se  -  cond's miens, but  u -  nique
> ```

**Note:** The title is just that, a title. No more, no less.

Comment: i don't have everything quite fitting in but looks like the 1st stanza is describing properties and 2nd stanza is talking about the structure of - _o#o##_ is it right?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly that would be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Let me post it as answer, if it is not what you have in mind will remove it.

Comment: is the odd structure of lining syllables up in columns necessary? It makes this difficult to read

Comment: It's purely for aesthetics, so no.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's

> Google!

In the first stanza,

> reading the first word of the first line, the second of the second, and so on gives:
>
> **G**lowing **O**xidizing **O**bsequious **G**orgeous **L**ife **E**minence.
>
>  Each line hints at that color of the Google logo (blue, red, yellow, blue, green, and red) and none of the other words start with those letters. (found by GentlePurpleRain)

In the second stanza,

> each line is a clue to a letter. The "bigger of twins" is one of two `G`s, but the only capitalized one; the "two doubles" are the same letter (`o`) but different colours in the logo;  the "second first" is the second occurrence of the first letter (another `g`, but lowercase); the "odd one" is the only non-rounded letter (`L`); and finally the letter `e` looks similar to the letter `o` in size and shape.

Comment: Correct all around, just missing some clues in the first stanza.

Comment: The first stanza is describing the colours of the letters:  Sky = blue, hot = red, son (sun) = yellow, sea = blue, life = green, cardinal (bird/priest) = red.

Comment: I also noticed that none of the other words in the first stanza (aside from the six you pointed out) start with those letters.

Comment: Yes, It was rather difficult to not use those starting letters.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be

> The sun

From the first riddle:

Glowing  brightly as though a sky

> Its a burning ball of gas

Freely    oxidizing will  make me hot

> It is very hot

Find      me        obsequious as         your       son

> son --> sun

Sparkling daily     as         gorgeous   as         sea

> It doesn't do much else

Slowly    but       surely     developing life       tendrils

> Plumes of erupting flames

Aviary    friend    and        church     associated eminence

> Son of God?

For the second:

This  big - ger  of     twins  is     my   star-ter

> Sun is a lot bigger than a son

These two   dou -bles   are    the    same but  not

> Pronounced the same, spelt different

The   se  - cond first, same   in     all  but  size

> Son is smaller than sun or vice versa

The   odd   one, not    like   an  -  y    o -  ther

> Not sure

This  last, the  se  -  cond's miens, but  u -  nique

> Not sure what that even means

Comment: Interesting idea, but going in a completely wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Hydrogen

Glowing brightly as though a sky

> The sun is made of hydrogen

Freely oxidizing will make me hot

> H2 reacts with every oxidizing element

Find me obsequious as your son

> The sun is made of hydrogen

Sparkling daily as gorgeous as sea

> The sun is made of hydrogen

These two dou -bles are the same but not
The se - cond first, same in all but size
The odd one, not like an - y o - ther
This  last, the  se  -  cond's miens, but  u -  nique

> I don't know enough about chemistry to say for sure, but I'm assuming this has to do with the different isotopes of hydrogen

Comment: This is a similar mindset to BeastlyGerbil's answer, and as such is still far in the wrong direction.